# Hat problem (Joint probability in the case of non-dependent random variable)

Tags: probability

(In a separate thread, I know that someone has already ask why $E[X_i X_j] = P(X_i X_j=1)$. But I want to check if my tackling of the entire question is correct.)

$n$ people go to their party. They throw their hats in a box at the beginning of a party. After the party, they pick one at random, without replacement.

Let $X$ be the random variable in which the person will pick up his/her OWN hat (success = $1$; failure = $0$). In addition, let $i$ be a person and $j$ be another person, where $i \neq j$.

How to calculate $E[X_i X_j]$?

I already know that $X_i X_j$ can only be $1$ or $0$, and so:

$$
E[X_i X_j] = \sum_{i,j: i \neq j} x_i x_j p_X(x_i x_j)
$$

The only condition for $x_i x_j$ to be of concerned here is $x_i x_j = 1$, because $x_i x_j = 0$ if either $x_i$ or $x_j$ is zero. In addition, between $i$ and $j$, the number of cross-product is $n^2-n$. Therefore,

$$
E[X_i X_j] = \sum_{i,j: i \neq j} (1) p_X(x_i x_j) = (n^2 - n) p_X(x_i x_j)
$$

Although $X$ (without replacement) is a non-independent random variable, the probability of the $i$ th person to get his own hat back is $\frac{1}{n}$. (Is my understanding correct here? I am a bit uncertain why it is the case even when $X$ is non-dependent. Any explanation will be appreciated.) When $i<j$, once you know that the $i$ th person can get his hat back, then you know that the probability of the $j$ th person to get his hat back is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Similarly, when $j<i$, once you know that the $j$ th person can get his hat back, then you know that the probability of the $i$ th person to get his hat back is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. Therefore:

$$
E[X_i X_j] = (n^2-n) \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{n-1} = 1
$$

I am pretty sure that my final answer is correct. However, I am sure if my understanding is correct. Particularly, I am unsure that if $X$ is not independent, the probability of any particular person to pick his hat is still $\frac{1}{n}$, when you have no knowledge of any person before

Comment: As you stated in the beginning: $~\mathsf E(X_iX_j) ~=~ \mathsf P(X_i=1, X_j=1) ~=~ \dfrac 1 {n(n-1)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to determine the variance of the count of people who select their own hat?

It seems that you have got the correct idea, but you are just not expressing it very well.

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf {Var}(X) ~=~& \mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2
\\[1ex]=~& \mathsf E\Big(\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\big)^2\Big)-\Big(\mathsf E\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\big)\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& \mathsf E\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n X_iX_j\Big)-\Big(\mathsf E\big(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\big)\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i^2)+\raise{1.5ex}{\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}\limits_{i\neq j}}\mathsf E(X_iX_j)-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf E(X_i)\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& \sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf P(X_i=1)+\raise{1.5ex}{\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}\limits_{i\neq j}}\mathsf P(X_i=1,X_j=1)-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\mathsf P(X_i=1)\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& \sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1 n+\raise{1.5ex}{\mathop{\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n}\limits_{i\neq j}}\frac 1{n(n-1)}-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1n\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& 1+1-\Big(1\Big)^2
\\[1ex]=~& 1
\end{align}$$

---

Because:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_i^2) ~=~& 0^2\mathsf P(X_i=0)+1^2\mathsf P(X_i=1)\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(X_i=1)\end{align}$$

And when $i\neq j$ then:
$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X_iX_j) ~=~& 0\mathsf P(X_i=0\cup X_j=0)+1\mathsf P(X_i=1\cap X_j=1)\\[1ex] =~& \mathsf P(X_i=1, X_j=1)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems.

First, the result must be wrong, since $X_iX_j\le1$, so if its expectation were $1$ that would mean that it takes the value $1$ almost surely, which it doesn't, since there are cases with finite (in fact high) probability in which one of the two doesn't take the correct hat.

Second, in the first displayed equation, $i$ and $j$ are free on the left but bound and summed over on the right. Perhaps you have a symmetry argument in mind here, and indeed a symmetry argument can be made, but you have to make it and can't just sum over $i,j$ on one side.

Third, the notation $p_X(x_ix_j)$ isn't introduced and isn't self-evident to me.

Fourth, you talk about $X$ being an independent or non-independent (meaning dependent?) variable. Random variables aren't independent or dependent on their own; this is a concept that applies to pairs or sets of random variables.

Comment: First, would it be more appropriate to say: Let $X_i$ be the random variable in which the person $i$ will pick up his/her OWN hat (success = 1; failure = 0), and thus $X$ is the random variable regarding the total number of person picking up their own hat? Second, I don't understand your second point. Third, $p_X(x_i x_j)$ is the joint probability that persons $i$ and $j$ having a particular value (1=picking up own hat; 0=otherwise). Fourth, $X_i$ and $X_j$ are dependent random variable, for all $i, j$

Comment: @Joseph: First: That's an improvement in the definitions, but it doesn't address my first point; the expectation of $X_iX_j$ can still not be $1$. Second: Do you know what free and bound variables are? If not, you can read up on them [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables). Third: I don't understand that sentence. Fourth: That's correct (but it's not what it says in the question).

Comment: @joriki Third: It seems that $p_X(x_ix_j)$ is meant to be $\mathsf P(X_i=x_i,X_j=x_j)$.  This is better represented as $p_{X_i,X_j}(x_i,x_j)$